# How do I prevent IE11 flexbox from having jumpy buttons on hover?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have a flexbox layout with buttons. When a user moves the mouse over the buttons, their positions jump around.

My source code is quite simple:

```css
.flexy { 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexy">
  <div>
    Content
  </div>
  <footer>
    <button>Button 1</button> <button>Button 2</button><br/>
    <button>Button 3</button> <button>Button 4</button><br/>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Moving the mouse between the two rows of buttons causes a lot of movement. Is there a fix I can use to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what's causing the problem. But I found that if you simply **add a border** to the button the shifting stops.

```css
.flexy { 
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 200px;
}

button {
  border: 1px solid #777;
  padding: 5px;            /* optional */
  margin: 5px;             /* optional */
}
```

```html
<div class='flexy'>
  <div>
    Content
  </div>
  <footer>
    <button>Button 1</button> <button>Button 2</button><br/>
    <button>Button 3</button> <button>Button 4</button><br/>
  </footer>
</div>
```

[**Revised Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/dw05jzdu/3/)

Comment: Thanks, this is a bit more flexible than the other in not needing to know specific heights. I combined it with an IE-only @media query so that other browser buttons aren't affected.

Answer (score 2):

Give your `footer` a `min-height` or `flex-basis` with the value being the actual height of the footer. I tested this in IE11, Chrome, Firefox, Safari and they all get along with this fix.

*Option 1*

```
footer {
  flex-basis: 46px;
}
```

*Option 2*

```
footer {
  min-height: 46px;
}
```